# custom library from maven not able to download for different version

Tags: java, android, maven, bintray, jcenter

I have a custom library uploaded to bintray maven with version 1.0.0

To download it for any project i have used the following code

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/<org or user name>/<repo-name>"
    }
}
```

And inside my app level build.gradle i have added the dependency

```
dependencies {
.....
compile 'my-group-id:artifactId:versionId'
.....
}
```

Recently i upgraded the versionId to 1.0.2 and it doesn't compile. For version 1.0.0 it compiles fine.

Heres the error i get

```
Error: Could not find sdk.jar (com.appunfold:sdk:1.0.2).
Searched in the following locations:
http://dl.bintray.com/appunfold/android/com/appunfold/sdk/1.0.2/sdk-1.0.2.jar
```

I checked the files inside 1.0.2. It contains **sdk-1.0.2.aar** (not sdk-1.0.2.jar)and compared it with the files inside 1.0.0. It contains the same with the version 1.0.0 i,e **sdk-1.0.0.aar**.

I couldn't find the reason why it is not able to download for a different version. Anybody faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after a deep few hours of research.

I think Android Studio by default searches for jar files. But since in my case only aar files are available i had to specify one more parameter (@aar) while compiling the dependency.

It looks like this

```
dependencies {
.....
compile 'my-group-id:artifactId:versionId:@aar'
.....
}
```